# Setting DefaultValue of a directive field type

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Please look at the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mejijuvize/edit?html,js,output)

You will notice that there are two fields.  One is a normal `input` while the other is a new field type that references `exampleDirective`. Please note...in my real application, these fields are pulling pulled from JSON and are not manually added to the `fields` array.

I set the `DefaultValue` on each record within the `fields` array. Again, these default values are being pulled from JSON.

The `RegularInput` field is properly displaying the default within its input field.

The `DirectiveInput` is not.  Please look at the model and you will see that the default value was applied to the field itself and not the input field (or fields if I had multiple) within the directive.

Is there a way to make `DefaultValue` work in this type of situation?  And if not...what would the best way to get the value that I am pulling from JSON to be placed on the directive fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing my issue by passing data INTO the directive.

```
formlyConfig.setType(
{
    name: 'dirTest1',
    template: '<div directive-test checked="to.IsChecked" amount="to.CoverageAmount"</div>'
});
```

With this approach, I can specify `IsChecked` and `CoverageAmount` in my directive and pass the values that I need when setting up the various inputs within the directive.  So, when I `push` this field type to my fields array, I can easily set my values like so:

```
var newRow = {
    key: TestKey,
    type: dirTest1,
    templateOptions: {
        CoverageAmount: 12345,
        IsChecked: true
    }
};
vm.fields[i].fieldGroup.push(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

just update your incoming json to include the "defaultValue" in the form object that gets passed to your directive. Try this: http://jsbin.com/coyuriyazu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I am adding the fields by `pushing` them to the `vm.fields` array. Meaning, I create a simple object and specify its key/type (the type being the directive in which has the input fields on it).  I don't think that I can pass the `defaultValue` to the directive this way.  Can I?

Comment: @JérémieBertrand Was your comment meant for Matthew?  I don't see what was wrong.  He includes the 'essential parts' in his post while also linking an example of what he was talking about.  I am just curious for future cases.

Comment: Matthew, you were the same dev that answered my question from yesterday, too.  http://jsbin.com/xecucenevu/3/edit?js,console,output  - I am using your method that you suggested but instead of adding simple input fields, I am adding custom field types that are directives and trying to set their `DefaultValue`s.

Comment: The comment was for Matthew, the explanation is here but it's also better if the source code is directly in the answer and not just in a link.